# Wrong Values in For Loop C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to print the values stored in Array l[] and r[] from array a[].
When I am trying to print values of array l[] its showing me invalid values.
But when I comment down the line which are providing values in array r[] from a[] the values of array l[] are then showing correct values.

I am providing input values 1 2 3 ... 10 and the output is comming 7 8 9 10 5 but when i comment lines which are providing values to arrar r[] the output is correct 1 2 3 4 5.

Why is this happening ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10], l[6], r[6],m = 0,n = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        l[i] = a[i];

    for(int i=5;i<10;i++)
        r[i] = a[i];  

    //l[6] = r[6] = 1e9;

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<l[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `l[6] = r[6] = 1e9;` is writing out-of-bounds values, and anything after that is undefined behaviour. Try: `l[5] = r[5] = 1e9;`. An array of 'n' values in C++ begins at index `0` and ends at index `n-1`.

Comment: for(int i=5;i<10;i++)
        r[i] = a[i];    Is also writing out of bounds on the r array.

Comment: Please consider adding what are you getting and what you expect.

Comment: I am providing input values 1 2 3 ... 10 and the output is comming 7 8 9 10 5 but when i comment lines which are providing values to arrar r the output is correct 1 2 3 4 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    cin>>a[i];  // this one looks OK

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    l[i] = a[i];  // this one looks OK too

for(int i=5;i<10;i++)
    r[i] = a[i];  // you access 'r' beyond 5 that damages other vars
```

Comment: My bad. Thanks brother.